# customizing file manager's top bar in gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I have GNOME Shell 3.16.4 installed on my Ubuntu 15.10 machine. However I get the old boring Unity like file manager. Here's a picture of my file Manager. See the top bar is like Ubuntu and button are on the left.

[image]

However, I want this my top bar completely like one below. Where you get to type the path. Also, you get the close, maximize and minimize button on the right and only back-forward buttons on the left.

[image]

Comment: @don_crissti thanks for the last answer. However, my question was a 3 question in one. All related to top bar.

Comment: @don_crissti yaa I should have according to the community guidelines but then I had to create multiple questions for such a small thing. Also asking question takes some waiting on stackexchange. You can't ask many questions in a line. I thought it won't be productive. I'll keep that in mind from next time :)

Comment: @don_crissti yaa the thing is I am noob. I could have searched if I knew its called nautilus and not file manager :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some simple command in your terminal:

To show the pathbar:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry false
```

To change the button layout:

- add the values at the left side of `:` for buttons on the left side

  `close,minimize,maximize:`

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close,minimize,maximize:"
  ```

  [image]
- add the values at the right side of `:` for buttons on the right side

  `:minimize,maximize,close`

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ":minimize,maximize,close"
  ```

  [image]
- or mix them

  `close:minimize,maximize`

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout "close:minimize,maximize"
  ```

  [image]

Comment: what about the windows like folder enter path?

Comment: Answer updated.